# JSON.net serializing untyped list as typed list?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

We have a list of objects, which we would like to serialize to a json string.
These objects have each a Property, which is an untyped ICollection.
The problem is, we would like to deserialize the JSON and compare it to another list, and on serializing, we have ofc the information, which type it is.

Since we can't change the property to a typed list, is it kindahow possible to tell JSON.NET: "It's untyped, but serialize it like it is typed of Type T?"

I guess, I could possibly cast it, when deserializing and kindahow pass the type, but this would be quite messy.

Edit: I use at the moment the messy way by casting the Data from JSON to the expected Type:

```
    private static void CastAssertDataSources(ReportDataSource dataSourceFromDb, ReportDataSource dataSourceFromJson)
    {
        var dtoType = dataSourceFromDb.Data.GetType().GetElementType();

        var dtosFromJson = new ArrayList(dataSourceFromJson.Data);
        ArrayList typedJsonDtos = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataSourceFromJson.Data.Count; i++)
        {
            var jsonDto = dtosFromJson[i];
            var containerJsonDto = (JContainer)jsonDto;
            var typedJsonDto = containerJsonDto.ToObject(dtoType);
            typedJsonDtos.Add(typedJsonDto);
        }

        dataSourceFromJson = new ReportDataSource(dataSourceFromJson.Name, typedJsonDtos);
        dataSourceFromDb.AssertIsEqualTo(dataSourceFromJson);
    }
```

"AssertisEqualTo" is an extension by us, but this shouldn't matter I guess.

Comment: Can you show what JSON is currently being created when serializing your untyped collection, and also what JSON you want to create?  Currently when Json.Net serializes an `ArrayList` it just serializes whatever happens to be there.

Comment: Yeah, the serialization is not the problem, but when I deserialize the JSON back, I get just an array of 'Jcontainer'- Objects. See my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your class looks something like this:

```
public class ReportDataSource 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection Data { get; set; }
}
```

You can do it with an appropriate [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm):

```
public sealed class TypedToTypelessCollectionConverter : JsonConverter
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static Type itemType;

    public static IDisposable SetItemType(Type deserializedType)
    {
        return new ItemType(deserializedType);
    }

    sealed class ItemType : IDisposable
    {
        Type oldType;

        internal ItemType(Type type)
        {
            this.oldType = itemType;
            itemType = type;
        }

        int disposed = 0;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Dispose of unmanaged resources.
            if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref disposed, 1) == 0)
            {
                // Free any other managed objects here.
                itemType = oldType;
                oldType = null;
            }
            // Suppress finalization.  Since this class actually has no finalizer, this does nothing.
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(ICollection);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; }}

    public override bool CanRead { get { return itemType != null; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return all interfaces implemented by the incoming type as well as the type itself if it is an interface.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfacesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (type.IsInterface)
            return new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces());
        else
            return type.GetInterfaces();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetEnumerableTypes(this Type type)
    {
        foreach (Type intType in type.GetInterfacesAndSelf())
        {
            if (intType.IsGenericType
                && intType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            {
                yield return intType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
public class ReportDataSource 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(TypedToTypelessCollectionConverter))]
    public ICollection Data { get; set; }

    public static ReportDataSource Deserialize(ReportDataSource dataSourceFromDb, string json)
    {
        using (TypedToTypelessCollectionConverter.SetItemType(dataSourceFromDb == null || dataSourceFromDb.Data == null ? null : dataSourceFromDb.Data.GetType().GetEnumerableTypes().SingleOrDefault()))
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReportDataSource>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that is an answer. I will give it a try as soon as possible. Thanks so far, I would upvote it twice if I could